# I am facing some errors in android studio after building the app, What can I do?

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio

After building the app
When I run it on my virtual device it doesn't even open it keeps stopping

**I checked the logcat**
I found the error but i cannot fix it :(

(((This is the error)))

```
at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6247)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5810)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5727)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1657)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6499)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:442)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 


at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzze.attachInfo(Unknown Source:17)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source:3)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6244)
            ... 10 more
```

Comment: Have you tried `> Clean Code` `> Rebuild Code` `> Invalidate cache and Restart` options ?

Answer (score 0):

Double check your gradle file for correct import of ad services and upgrade all dependencies to the latest versions. Check out [Set Up Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) for more details. I say this because your error code states: 
 `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzze.attachInfo(Unknown Source:17)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source:3)`

This seems to suggest that `gms.ads` is attempting to attach and the source is unknown. Please post your gradle files or more of the error code if updating the dependencies doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Add your AppId in your manifest file like this

```
<manifest>
<application>
    <!-- TODO: Replace with your real AdMob app ID -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-################~##########"/>
</application>
```

https://ads-developers.googleblog.com/2018/10/announcing-v1700-of-android-google.html